# Build a CMake project with Nix

Tags: cmake, kde-plasma, nix, nixos

I'm trying to make a derivation from [fokus (a KDE plasmoid)](https://gitlab.com/divinae/focus-plasmoid).

I have a `default.nix` which looks like:

```
{ mkDerivation, lib, fetchFromGitLab, cmake, extra-cmake-modules
, plasma-framework
, qt5 }:

let
  version = "1.5.4";
  repo = fetchFromGitLab {
    owner = "divinae";
    repo = "focus-plasmoid";
    rev = "v${version}";
    sha256 = "19nndmqfzdcg7lzcifxa17m2mx85dlf4m2wxzr72gf78h4yj0ahv";
  };
in
  mkDerivation rec {
    inherit version;
    pname = "fokus";

    src = "${repo}/packages";
    dontUnpack = true;

    buildInputs  = [
      plasma-framework
      qt5.qtbase
    ];

    nativeBuildInputs = [ cmake extra-cmake-modules ];

    meta = with lib; {
      description = "Simple pomodoro timer plasmoid";
      homepage = "https://store.kde.org/p/1308861/";
      license = licenses.gpl3Only;
      maintainers = with maintainers; [  ];
      platforms = platforms.unix;
    };
  }
```

I also added to `all-packages`:

```
fokus-plasma-applet = libsForQt5.callPackage ../applications/misc/fokus-plasma-applet { };
```

The thing is, I have only find few examples in nixpkgs, and I do not see what to do with this error (since `CMakeLists.txt` is effectively in `/package`):

```
building '/nix/store/c21h5667abmj4v0ci4n51ckvkxvc23gk-fokus-1.5.4.drv'...
qtPreHook
patching sources
configuring
fixing cmake files...
cmake flags: -DCMAKE_FIND_USE_SYSTEM_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=OFF -DCMAKE_FIND_USE_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=OFF -DCMAKE_EXPORT_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH=ON -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LOCALEDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share/locale -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBEXECDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/libexec -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/lib -DCMAKE_INSTALL_DOCDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share/doc/fokus -DCMAKE_INSTALL_INFODIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share/info -DCMAKE_INSTALL_MANDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share/man -DCMAKE_INSTALL_OLDINCLUDEDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/include -DCMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/include -DCMAKE_INSTALL_SBINDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/sbin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/bin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_DIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/lib -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0025=NEW -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT= -DCMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK=LAST -DCMAKE_STRIP=/nix/store/4g5fidyk19akng9n91cql60ylrjq93s6-gcc-wrapper-10.3.0/bin/strip -DCMAKE_RANLIB=/nix/store/ffcrrgb6k5h7crr93dj90bi9fy1jvj16-binutils-2.35.1/bin/ranlib -DCMAKE_AR=/nix/store/ffcrrgb6k5h7crr93dj90bi9fy1jvj16-binutils-2.35.1/bin/ar -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4  -DKDE_INSTALL_EXECROOTDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4 -DKDE_INSTALL_BINDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/bin -DKDE_INSTALL_SBINDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/sbin -DKDE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/lib -DKDE_INSTALL_LIBEXECDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/libexec -DKDE_INSTALL_CMAKEPACKAGEDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/lib/cmake -DKDE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/include -DKDE_INSTALL_LOCALSTATEDIR=/var -DKDE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share -DKDE_INSTALL_DATADIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share -DKDE_INSTALL_DOCBUNDLEDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share/doc/HTML -DKDE_INSTALL_KCFGDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share/config.kcfg -DKDE_INSTALL_KCONFUPDATEDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share/kconf_update -DKDE_INSTALL_KSERVICES5DIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share/kservices5 -DKDE_INSTALL_KSERVICETYPES5DIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share/kservicetypes5 -DKDE_INSTALL_KXMLGUI5DIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share/kxmlgui5 -DKDE_INSTALL_KNOTIFY5RCDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share/knotifications5 -DKDE_INSTALL_ICONDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share/icons -DKDE_INSTALL_LOCALEDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share/locale -DKDE_INSTALL_SOUNDDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share/sounds -DKDE_INSTALL_TEMPLATEDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share/templates -DKDE_INSTALL_WALLPAPERDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share/wallpapers -DKDE_INSTALL_APPDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share/applications -DKDE_INSTALL_DESKTOPDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share/desktop-directories -DKDE_INSTALL_MIMEDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share/mime/packages -DKDE_INSTALL_METAINFODIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share/appdata -DKDE_INSTALL_MANDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share/man -DKDE_INSTALL_INFODIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share/info -DKDE_INSTALL_DBUSDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share/dbus-1 -DKDE_INSTALL_DBUSINTERFACEDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share/dbus-1/interfaces -DKDE_INSTALL_DBUSSERVICEDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share/dbus-1/services -DKDE_INSTALL_DBUSSYSTEMSERVICEDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/share/dbus-1/system-services -DKDE_INSTALL_SYSCONFDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/etc -DKDE_INSTALL_CONFDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/etc/xdg -DKDE_INSTALL_AUTOSTARTDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/etc/xdg/autostart -DKDE_INSTALL_QTPLUGINDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/lib/qt-5.15.2/plugins -DKDE_INSTALL_PLUGINDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/lib/qt-5.15.2/plugins -DKDE_INSTALL_QMLDIR=/nix/store/5rdpaqmcj9hrpwdcnprr0zm51659mp08-fokus-1.5.4/lib/qt-5.15.2/qml 
CMake Error: The source directory "/build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
builder for '/nix/store/c21h5667abmj4v0ci4n51ckvkxvc23gk-fokus-1.5.4.drv' failed with exit code 1
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/b9jhnh8bix892wql3qifvgf742lq41v9-system-path.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/3n3mwi7vqmnkng6r8kpa9881xdgcd253-nixos-system-looping-21.11pre328987.c935f5e0add.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
error: build of '/nix/store/3n3mwi7vqmnkng6r8kpa9881xdgcd253-nixos-system-looping-21.11pre328987.c935f5e0add.drv' failed
```

Comment: I believe you have a typo there? In your nix expression you reference `packages`, while the repo only contains a `package` directory.